# Как сделать эффект печатающегося текста на python?

Tags: python, строки, текст, автоматизация, печать

Я хочу сделать python программу, которая будет запускать концовку игры portal (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6ljFaKRTrI&t=54s) в консоли, но для этого мне нужен эффект печатающегося текста, я новичок и не знаю, как его сделать.
я попытался использовать такой код:

```
import time
text = "h"
print(text, end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'h')
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'he')
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'hel')
print(text, end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'hell')
print(text, end='', flush=True)
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'hello')
time.sleep(0.1)
print('\b' * len(text) + 'hello!')
```

Comment: _я попытался использовать такой код_ - и? что не так?

Answer (score 11):

```
import time

txt = 'текст который нужен'
for i in txt:  # этот цикл будет брать по 1 буковке из тхт
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
```

чтобы вывод в строку сработал как задумано, а не сразу написал всё сообщение нужно добавить `flush=True`
(надеюсь у вас последняя версия питона, на старых иначе делается)

Answer (score 0):

```html
text = "Hello!"
text = list(text)
out_text = ""
for i in text:
    out_text += i
    os.system("cls")
    print(out_text)
```

Это если через консоль будешь выводить, ну если ты красиво делаешь со сменой так сказать локаций