# Как выводить текст побуквенно с паузами?

Tags: python

```
def print_hor(print_hor = str(), sec2 = int()):

    for j in print_hor:
        sleep(sec2) 
        print(j, end = "")
```

Так вот, эта функция должна выводить текст с определенными временными промежутками
Пример: П (0.03 секунды прошло) р (0,03) и (0.03) в (0.03) е (0.03) т (0.03). Так выводится слово "Привет"

А по итогу указанное время проходит, текст выводится сразу же полностью. Сам сижу с Linux'a, может с ним какая то фигня

Comment: вон там ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171906/Как-сделать-эффект-печатающегося-текста-на-python/1171915#1171915

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но на самом деле нужно было указать параметр flush в значении True

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает, попробуйте сделать промежуток побольше, например, секунда

```
import time
def print_hor(print_hor = str(), sec2 = int()):
  for j in print_hor:
    time.sleep(sec2) 
    print(j, end = "")
        
print_hor( 'Привет', 1 )
```

Comment: проверьте,у вас будет такаяже "проблема"

Comment: @Интик я всё проверил на мак оси. Буквы появляются медленно, сначало П затем Пр далее При очень красиво, мне нравится